# What’s a word for someone who should face karma but never does?

Tags: single-word-requests

What’s a word that is similarly defined as someone who never faces karma or consequences for their actions regardless of how deserved they are of it?

For example:

> This person is _____, they’re always getting away with doing bad things!

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 3):

[**Teflon**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/teflon), as assigned to a person and not a pan, is the quality of infinite deflection—nothing sticks there.

Cambridge Dictionary online says it's an adjective for "someone who manages to avoid criticism and keep a good reputation, even after they have done something wrong."

Of course, the urban use of *teflon* bounces directly off the plastic non-stick coating for pots and pans that Dupont invented.